# Creating login script via jmeter for a public website

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing, blazemeter

I am using Blazemeter load testing plugin for chrome and I recorded a login script of a website which is not owned by me. How ever when i try to assert via jmeter to verify whether I have successfully logged in via response assertion it fails.

Further when i look in to the result tree - html content it shows that the script has not loged in hence the assertion fails.

I tried several videos but still can not find out the issue. Any suggestions

Comment: Did you do the data correlation ?

Comment: you mean examine the post request and set the key values right yes i did set it manually also

Comment: You have to also check the values which are passed internally e.g. Session ID etc.
these are dynamic values, you will have to use regular expressions to extract these and set them in the login request

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you using 2 login request. 1st for GET and 2nd for POST.

You need to pass username , password when you do POST.

Comment: Hi why do we need to have a Get request as well? My script directly points to the url path which is loaded when the sign in button is hit followed by the respective post parameters

Comment: You are right but it does not work in that way. GET and POST together. Fist get login page and post in same page with parameters. User HTTP request default to pass main URL only at once.

Comment: ok..please mark my answer as useful if you get success login using my given info.

Comment: sure thing bro, I modified the script but it fails. So if I am not mistaken you are telling to have to samplers right? one directing to login page with get and another sampler again to the same page with a post followed by the post parameters right. Also i now use a http request default too. Still it fails and the html response is directed to the home page but the user has not logged in

Comment: Your testing site is in Asp.net? or php? or other?

Comment: Okay then you should pass user name , password and session ID when you post. Please pass actual values not variables like ${username}. Also add Http cookie manager at top.

Comment: I have passed actual values after examining a real post made to website and then set it in the sample. But still it does not work any way thanks for the help I shall check it up!

Comment: Okay. keep trying. If anything do not work. then you can use recording control to login as per below video :                                       http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/201038-jmeter-video-tutorial-recording-a-user-session-wi

Answer (score 0):

1. Try adding [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your test plan, if the problem is in missing cookies it'll automatically handle it. If there are any hard-coded cookies after recording in HTTP Header Manager aka "Browser-derived headers" - remove them.
2. Try recording your login flow sequence for several times and see if there are any dynamic parameters (request values which change from one request to another). If they are - they need to be extracted from first response and added to next request.
3. Check [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter) guide out. It contains correlation example specific for .NET web applications but general steps should be the same and could be applied to any server-side tecnhology.